# TableView Custom cell does not Enter the init method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My problem is the cell is created but it dose not called any init Method。I don't use a xib. here is my simple code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _tabV = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [_tabV registerClass:[TestCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    _tabV.delegate = self;
    _tabV.dataSource = self;


    [self.view addSubview:_tabV];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 100;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    TestCell  * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    return cell;

}
```

and the cell:

```
- (instancetype)init{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return self;
}


- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
         self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    return  self;
}
```

but either [init] or [initWithFram] did called. it's a quite simple problem i think. but i just don't know where goes wrong...

Comment: The designated initializers for `UITableViewCell` are [initWithCoder:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623220-initwithcoder?language=objc) and [initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623276-initwithstyle?language=objc). So you don't expect to have any of the call you mentioned.

Comment: oh...i regards the cell as a normal view...you are right .thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UITableViewCell` subclass should implement `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` or `initWithCoder:` initializer. The standard init methods of a view won't work in this case.

More details here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell?language=objc